# Ubuntu 22.04: Change the font color and font shadow in dash-to-panel gnome extension

Tags: gnome, themes, fonts

Is it possible to change the font color and the font shadow in dash-to-panel?

Choosing a light background color makes the text unintelligible, because it remains white. I looked into the `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/stylesheet.css` and added a `color: red !important;` in the class `.dashtopanelMainPanel` just to test if anything would change, so I could start experimenting, but nothing happened.

I also looked into the current theme's `~/.themes/Orchis-Orange-Light/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` file but I could still not find any clue as to which class needs to change, if any.

AFAIK there is no way to change these things from within the dash-to-panel options.

Constant testing is also cumbersome because I am on Wayland and there is no good way to restart gnome, other than logging out and back in, so if someone can direct me to the correct files and CSS classes, I will manage to figure it out from there, just so that I am not searching blindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending quite some time on this, I got it.

The text in the right side of the dash-to-panel bottom bar is controlled by the `#panel .panel-button` selector and the "Show all apps" icon color is controlled by `.show-apps .overview-icon`

You can figure out the rest from there.

P.S. it's the applied shell theme that styles that part of the bottom panel, not the "applications/legacy" theme.